# Docker でコンテナのルートディレクトリサイズを大きくしたい

Tags: docker

CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611
で、dockerをインストールしました。コンテナのルート(`/`)の容量がデフォルトで10Gしかないので50Gに増やしたいと思います。

下記のページを参考に、以下の作業を行いました。

[Dockerで各containerの初期ディスクサイズを拡張する - Qiita](http://qiita.com/dempasong/items/fafa4b1fe1fc8d9f452d)

```sh
systemctl stop docker.service
$ sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/docker

    other_args=" --storage-opt dm.basesize=50G"
```

を追加

```sh
$ sudo mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker.back
$ sudo mkdir /var/lib/docker
$ systemctl start docker.service
```

しかし、`systemctl start` を実行すると以下のエラーが発生します。

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units === Authentication is required to manage system services or units.
Authenticating as: teotsuka Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE === Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status
docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

/var/lib/docker を削除（中身を削除）したのが原因だと思われますが、どのように対処したらよろしいのでしょうか？

ご存知の方、ご教示いただきたくよろしくお願いします。

Comment: `/var/lib/docker.back`と`/var/lib/docker`のオーナーおよびアクセス権は同じでしょうか。

Comment: エラーはでなくなりましたが、コンテナのルート(/)の容量がデフォルトで10Gのままです。

Comment: /etc/sysconfig/docker-storageに「DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS=" --storage-opt dm.basesize=50G"を加えるとできました。

Comment: @Ubunkun 古い質問を見てたらたまたま見つけました。  問題が解決した場合には、後学のためにも、その内容を自己回答お願いできますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/etc/sysconfig/docker-storage に以下の記述を加えることで、やりたい事が実現できました。

```
DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS=" --storage-opt dm.basesize=50G"
```

---

*この投稿は @Ubunkun さんのコメント の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*